# Asus tablet/laptop

Tags: passwords, password-management, password-cracking, password-reset, default-password

I need to crack my Asus. My roommate put a password on it and I can't figure it out. The password hint on the login page says crazed. If anybody knows how to get in this M.F. P.O.S. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may need rubber-hose cryptanalysis. Take your room-mate, and tie him to a chair. Beat him with a tire iron until he confesses.